manual tmp dir is being deleted inside jenkins agent pod
Team,
i am are running bazel and wanted to use a new dir for its cache. so created a dir using jenkins stage and it works fine. but somehow the dir is being deleted and am not sure what could be causing its deletion. is there a way I can figure this out? or am i creating dir in a wrong way?
stage1
export TMPDIR=/home/jenkins/agent/tmp
mkdir -p /home/jenkins/agent/tmp

stage2
bazel initializes and creates cache in that dir above.

stage3 shows that dir was deleted.
WriteFile trivial.c failed: open /tmp/go-link-3818880843/trivial.c: no such file or directory
external/go_sdk/pkg/tool/linux_amd64/link: cannot create /tmp/go-link-3818880843/000022.o: open /tmp/go-link-3818880843/000022.o: no such file or directory


So, you make /home/jenkins/agent/tmp directory but then cannot find /tmp/go-link-3818880843 directory. How are those two directories related?

oh that is how in logs /tmp/go_* is referred due to trimming I guess.

Your TMPDIR variable gets lost because Jenkins doesn't keep the environment variables between different sh calls. If you want to set it globally in your pipeline add it to the environment directive inside the pipeline block.
